# Spring REQUIRES_NEW inner transaction does not get persisted

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa, spring-data, spring-transactions

When I run the below code, the inner transaction with REQUIRES_NEW does not get persisted to the DB. Only foo@foo.com gets persisted. If I remove Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW from the inner transaction, then both records get persisted. Why is REQUIRES_NEW not working as expected here?

I'd appreciate any thoughts!

Notes:

1. I'm running the code with [outer = true, inner = true]
2. I am using @EnableTransactionManagement(mode = AdviceMode.PROXY)
3. A bean is created for each service (i.e. FooService and BarService)

**FooController:**

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/api/v1")
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Slf4j
public class FooController {
    
    private final FooService fooService;
    
    @RequestMapping(value = "/test-transactions", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ResponseEntity<Void> testTransactions(
            @RequestParam(value = "outer", required = true) boolean isOuterSuccessful,
            @RequestParam(value = "inner", required = true) boolean isInnerSuccessful) {
        
        log.debug("Running with params - Outer: {}, Inner: {}", isOuterSuccessful, isInnerSuccessful);
        fooService.doFoo(isOuterSuccessful, isInnerSuccessful);
        
        
        return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT);
    }
}
```

**FooService:**

```
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Slf4j
public class FooService {
    
    private final BarService barService;
    private final FooRepository repo;
    
    @Transactional
    public void doFoo(boolean isOuterSuccessful, boolean isInnerSuccessful) {
        
        FooEntity sub = FooEntity.builder()
                .emailAddress("foo@foo.com")
                .build();
        
        sub = repo.save(sub);
        log.debug("Persisted Foo - ID: {}, email: {}", sub.getSubscriberId(), sub.getEmailAddress());
        
        try {
            barService.doBar(isInnerSuccessful);
        } catch (RuntimeException e) {
            log.debug("Caught exception from BarService!", e);
        }
        
        if (!isOuterSuccessful) {
            log.debug("Foo (outer transaction) should rollback");
            throw new RuntimeException("Foo Service (Outer Transaction)");
        }
    }
}
```

**BarService:**

```
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Slf4j
public class BarService {
    
    private final FooRepository repo;
    
    @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)  // DOESN'T WORK
    // @Transactional // WORKS
    public void doBar(boolean isInnerSuccessful) {
        
        FooEntity sub = FooEntity.builder()
                .emailAddress("bar@bar.com")
                .build();
        
        sub = repo.save(sub);
        log.debug("Persisted Bar - ID: {}, email: {}", sub.getSubscriberId(), sub.getEmailAddress());
        
        if (!isInnerSuccessful) {
            log.debug("Bar (inner transaction) should rollback");
            throw new RuntimeException("Bar Service (Inner Transaction)");
        }
    }
}
```

**ControllerProvider:**

```
@Slf4j
public class ControllerProvider {
        
    @Autowired private ServiceProvider serviceProvider;
    @Autowired private RepositoryProvider repositoryProvider;
    // other providers...
    
    @Bean
    public FooController fooController() {
        return new FooController(serviceProvider.fooService());
    }

    // other controller beans...
}
```

**ServiceProvider:**

```
@Configuration
@Import({ RepositoryProvider.class, 
    DataSourceProvider.class,
    // others...
})
@Slf4j
public class ServiceProvider {

    @Autowired private RepositoryProvider repositoryProvider;
    // others...

    @Bean
    public FooService fooService() {
        return new FooService(barService(), repositoryProvider.getSubscriberRepo());
    }
    
    @Bean
    public BarService barService() {
        return new BarService(repositoryProvider.getSubscriberRepo2());
    }

    // other beans...
}
```

**DataSourceProvider:**

```
@Configuration
@Import(EnvironmentProvider.class)
@EnableTransactionManagement(mode = AdviceMode.PROXY)
@Slf4j
public class DataSourceProvider {
    
    @Autowired EnvironmentProvider envProvider;
    
    @Bean
    DataSource dataSource() {
        
        final AppConfig env = envProvider.envConfig();
        
        MysqlDataSource dataSource = new MysqlDataSource();    
        dataSource.setUrl(env.findProperty("db.url"));
        dataSource.setPortNumber( Integer.parseInt(env.findProperty("db.port")) );
        dataSource.setUser(env.findProperty("db.username"));
        dataSource.setPassword(env.findProperty("db.password"));
        return dataSource;
    }
    
    @Bean
    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {
                
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactoryBean = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource());
        
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setPackagesToScan(
                "com.abc.service.core.entities",
                "com.abc.service",
                "com.abc.backend.shared.entities"
                );
        
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setPersistenceUnitName("ABC");
        
        HibernateJpaVendorAdapter va = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setJpaVendorAdapter(va);
        
        Properties ps = new Properties();
        ps.put("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect");
        ps.put("hibernate.connection.shutdown", "true");
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setJpaProperties(ps);
        return entityManagerFactoryBean;
    }
    
    @Bean
    SpringContextProvider contextProvider() {
        return new SpringContextProvider();
    }
    
    @Bean(name="transactionManager")
    @PersistenceContext(unitName="ABC")
    public PlatformTransactionManager txManager() {
        JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory().getNativeEntityManagerFactory());
        return transactionManager;
    }
}
```

LOGS:

```
[DEBUG] 09-11-2021 22:57:52,953 (http-nio-8080-exec-4) []  | rest_filters.SimpleCORSFilter:46 - HTTP REQUEST METHOD: POST -> http://localhost:8080/api/v1/test-transactions (origin: null)
[DEBUG] 09-11-2021 22:57:52,954 (http-nio-8080-exec-4) []  | rest_filters.SimpleCORSFilter:47 - Access-Control-Request-Method: null
[DEBUG] 09-11-2021 22:57:52,954 (http-nio-8080-exec-4) []  | rest_filters.SimpleRequestLoggingFilter:23 - BEFORE REQUEST  [POST /api/v1/test-transactions]

[DEBUG] 09-11-2021 22:57:52,954 (http-nio-8080-exec-4) []  | provider.SentryTracesSampler:39 - Sentry tracing firing...
[DEBUG] 09-11-2021 22:57:52,956 (http-nio-8080-exec-4) [] anonymousUser | foo.FooController:26 - Running with params - Outer: true, Inner: true
[DEBUG] 09-11-2021 22:57:52,956 (http-nio-8080-exec-4) [] anonymousUser | support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager:370 - Creating new transaction with name [com.offtherecord.service.foo.FooService.doFoo]: PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,ISOLATION_DEFAULT
[DEBUG] 09-11-2021 22:57:52,956 (http-nio-8080-exec-4) [] anonymousUser | jpa.JpaTransactionManager:412 - Opened new EntityManager [SessionImpl(2094541306<open>)] for JPA transaction
[DEBUG] 09-11-2021 22:57:53,809 (http-nio-8080-exec-4) [] anonymousUser | jpa.JpaTransactionManager:375 - Found thread-bound EntityManager [SessionImpl(2094541306<open>)] for JPA transaction
[DEBUG] 09-11-2021 22:57:53,810 (http-nio-8080-exec-4) [] anonymousUser | support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager:470 - Participating in existing transaction
[DEBUG] 09-11-2021 22:57:54,719 (http-nio-8080-exec-4) [] anonymousUser | foo.FooService:24 - Persisted Foo - ID: 119, email: foo@foo.com
[DEBUG] 09-11-2021 22:57:54,720 (http-nio-8080-exec-4) [] anonymousUser | jpa.JpaTransactionManager:375 - Found thread-bound EntityManager [SessionImpl(2094541306<open>)] for JPA transaction
[DEBUG] 09-11-2021 22:57:54,720 (http-nio-8080-exec-4) [] anonymousUser | support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager:429 - Suspending current transaction, creating new transaction with name [com.offtherecord.service.foo.BarService.doBar]
[DEBUG] 09-11-2021 22:57:54,720 (http-nio-8080-exec-4) [] anonymousUser | jpa.JpaTransactionManager:412 - Opened new EntityManager [SessionImpl(1830775810<open>)] for JPA transaction
[DEBUG] 09-11-2021 22:57:55,541 (http-nio-8080-exec-4) [] anonymousUser | jpa.JpaTransactionManager:375 - Found thread-bound EntityManager [SessionImpl(1830775810<open>)] for JPA transaction
[DEBUG] 09-11-2021 22:57:55,541 (http-nio-8080-exec-4) [] anonymousUser | support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager:470 - Participating in existing transaction
[DEBUG] 09-11-2021 22:57:55,542 (http-nio-8080-exec-4) [] anonymousUser | foo.BarService:23 - Persisted Bar - ID: null, email: bar@bar.com
[TRACE] 09-11-2021 22:57:55,542 (http-nio-8080-exec-4) [] anonymousUser | support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager:917 - Triggering beforeCommit synchronization
[TRACE] 09-11-2021 22:57:55,543 (http-nio-8080-exec-4) [] anonymousUser | support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager:930 - Triggering beforeCompletion synchronization
[DEBUG] 09-11-2021 22:57:55,543 (http-nio-8080-exec-4) [] anonymousUser | support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager:740 - Initiating transaction commit
[DEBUG] 09-11-2021 22:57:55,543 (http-nio-8080-exec-4) [] anonymousUser | jpa.JpaTransactionManager:557 - Committing JPA transaction on EntityManager [SessionImpl(1830775810<open>)]
[TRACE] 09-11-2021 22:57:55,678 (http-nio-8080-exec-4) [] anonymousUser | support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager:943 - Triggering afterCommit synchronization
[TRACE] 09-11-2021 22:57:55,678 (http-nio-8080-exec-4) [] anonymousUser | support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager:960 - Triggering afterCompletion synchronization
[DEBUG] 09-11-2021 22:57:55,678 (http-nio-8080-exec-4) [] anonymousUser | jpa.JpaTransactionManager:648 - Closing JPA EntityManager [SessionImpl(1830775810<open>)] after transaction
[DEBUG] 09-11-2021 22:57:55,678 (http-nio-8080-exec-4) [] anonymousUser | support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager:1008 - Resuming suspended transaction after completion of inner transaction
[TRACE] 09-11-2021 22:57:55,679 (http-nio-8080-exec-4) [] anonymousUser | support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager:917 - Triggering beforeCommit synchronization
[TRACE] 09-11-2021 22:57:55,679 (http-nio-8080-exec-4) [] anonymousUser | support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager:930 - Triggering beforeCompletion synchronization
[DEBUG] 09-11-2021 22:57:55,679 (http-nio-8080-exec-4) [] anonymousUser | support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager:740 - Initiating transaction commit
[DEBUG] 09-11-2021 22:57:55,679 (http-nio-8080-exec-4) [] anonymousUser | jpa.JpaTransactionManager:557 - Committing JPA transaction on EntityManager [SessionImpl(2094541306<open>)]
[TRACE] 09-11-2021 22:57:55,818 (http-nio-8080-exec-4) [] anonymousUser | support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager:943 - Triggering afterCommit synchronization
[TRACE] 09-11-2021 22:57:55,961 (http-nio-8080-exec-4) [] anonymousUser | support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager:960 - Triggering afterCompletion synchronization
[DEBUG] 09-11-2021 22:57:55,961 (http-nio-8080-exec-4) [] anonymousUser | jpa.JpaTransactionManager:648 - Closing JPA EntityManager [SessionImpl(2094541306<open>)] after transaction
[DEBUG] 09-11-2021 22:57:55,963 (http-nio-8080-exec-4) [] anonymousUser | rest_filters.SimpleRequestLoggingFilter:29 - AFTER REQUEST    [POST /api/v1/test-transactions]
```

Comment: Maybe `barService.doBar();` is throwing an exception, which you ignore.

Comment: Do you see any exception or database is simply not updated?

Comment: Thanks for the comments! There’s no exception being thrown. FooService and BarService both perform the same simple task. An exception would also appear in the logs and no such luck. 

The call seemingly succeeds but only foo@ gets persisted in the DB.

Comment: No, it would not because you are actively doing nothing about the exception and just swallowing it. At least add `e.printStackTrace()` or a better logging option so that we know if an exception is or is not thrown.

Comment: Fair point. I do have a log statement there but I removed all log statements in the question for brevity. I’ll add it back with a comment. Thanks!

Comment: Ok, I've added some comments back in and provided log output. Let me know if anything else would be useful. I'm really stumped here.